# pthread error code 3029 on the as400/IBM I?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, ibm-midrange

I have the following C source:

```
#define _MULTI_THREADED
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* threadfunc(void* parm){
    printf("Hello thread.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t t;
    int rc;
    rc = pthread_create(&t, NULL, threadfunc, NULL);
    printf("Create return code: %i\n", rc);
    if(!rc){
        pthread_join(t, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `crtbndc pgm(test) srcfile(myfile) srcmbr(test)`

When called with `call test`, I get the output:

> Create return code: 3029

What does this error code mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to IBM i [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/concept4.htm), pthreads doesn't seem to be supported:

> Thread creation (pthread_create()) fails with EBUSY or 3029
>
> Because many parts of the operating system are not yet thread safe,
> not every job can start threads. The pthread_create() API fails with
> the EBUSY error when the process is not allowed to create threads. See
> Running threaded programs for information about how to start a job
> that can create threads.

And it suggests a few [alternatives](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/293735.htm).

Comment: I was going to post my next question, but since I can only post once every 90 minutes, I will ask here. I tried one of the alternatives which is to start the job with the command SBMJOB, but this way doesn't print the job print calls to my screen. How do I make a job launched with SBMJOB print to my screen like it would if called directly with the CALL command?

Comment: The submitted job runs in *batch* mode separate from the local workstation, and unlike \*nix, the IBM i, being object-based, does not treat everything as a *file* that can be opened, so the terminal can not so easily be written to from the other job as might be the case with another OS. Probably easiest to try a different of the *alternatives* offered; notably, using `QSH` to initiate the `test.pgm` after `ADDENVVAR QIBM_MULTI_THREADED 'Y'`

Answer (score 1):

Error return codes can be interpreted most easily by looking the message description for the related message ID. Use the prefix 'CPE' with the character return code '3029'. So for this one, see this command:

```
DSPMSGD CPE3029
```

In this case, the 1st-level text is "Resource busy." This likely refers to the display file/device that is already in active use and is allocated to the job's primary thread (assuming the CALL was made in an interactive job).

In a program, you might review the [Checking the Errno Value](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarh/hchkerrno.htm) topic in the ILE C/C++ Programmer's Guide. The ERRNO member in the H source file in library QSYSINC should also be reviewed.

Also, a table of [Errno Values for UNIX-Type Functions](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/unix14.htm) is in the Knowledge Center.